# custom animation for navigation between pages Xamarin.forms?

Tags: navigation, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I create simple App using Xamarin.Forms and need to set the navigation to up & down instate of left & right

Comment: There was a [discussion on Xamarin forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18818/custom-page-transitions-with-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want up & down animation (not custom animation), you could simply use `Navigation.PushModalAsync(page)` to present the page .

---

Besides, I just wrote a custom renderer to change animation on iOS.

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(AnimationNavigationRenderer))]

class AnimationNavigationRenderer : NavigationRenderer
{
    public override void PushViewController(UIViewController viewController, bool animated)
    {
        if (animated)
        {
            // Alternative way with different set of trannsition
            /*
            UIView.Animate(0.75, () =>
            {
                UIView.SetAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseInOut);
                base.PushViewController(viewController, false);
                UIView.SetAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.CurlUp, this.View, false);
            });
             */
            var transition = CATransition.CreateAnimation();
            transition.Duration = 0.75;
            transition.Type = CAAnimation.TransitionPush;

            View.Layer.AddAnimation(transition, null);
            base.PushViewController(viewController, false);
        }
        else
        {
            base.PushViewController(viewController, false);
        }
    }

    public override UIViewController PopViewController(bool animated)
    {
        if (animated)
        {
            // Alternative way with different set of trannsition
            /*                UIView.Animate(0.75, () =>
            {
                UIView.SetAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseInOut);
                UIView.SetAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.CurlDown, this.View, false);
            });
            */

            var transition = CATransition.CreateAnimation();
            transition.Duration = 0.75;
            transition.Type = CAAnimation.TransitionFromTop;

            View.Layer.AddAnimation(transition, null);

            return base.PopViewController(false);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.PopViewController(false);
        }
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/alexlau811/e12a8c126e6e082a5017

Comment: Thanks Alex for helping it works good
Now I need to know the event when click on page and move my finger up push the next page.
**what is the event should I fire ??**

Comment: Do you mean you wish to let user drag the whole page up and reveal another page underneath?

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. I've copied your code into a AnimationNavigationRenderer.cs file and put it in iOS/Renderers folder. Are there any other steps required? I changed the transition.Duration to 5, but it's the same speed. I'm using `await CURRENT_PAGE.Navigation.PushModalAsync(NEXT_PAGE, true);` and `Navigation.PopModalAsync();`