# Animation in the transition between forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

There is such a problem. When switching from the main form to others, you should show the standard animation; the circle is spinning, here is the code, but the animation is not displayed.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private async void PlayBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new PlayPage(),true);
        }
        private async void RateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new RatePage(),true);
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9SdL.jpg)

Comment: You really need to stop asking, deleting and reposting this question. If you want custom Page to Page animations, they are not supported "out of the box", you will need to code it, review this answer as a start (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696927/custom-animation-for-navigation-between-pages-xamarin-forms) If you are just looking for a busy indictor on a page after it initially gets push into the navigation stack, review ActivityIndicator : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.ActivityIndicator

Comment: For standard Push animation make sure your mainpage is wrapped in a NavigationPage